# Fluid physics won't work inside hollow object

Tags: physics, fluid-simulation

I'm really new to this program and just got into the physics simulations.   I'll attach the [blend file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1RoSpw3qC3sFK8GZAUw9_iVgNDAvRXH65) but this is the basic idea:

I have a hollow apple with a bite in it that's floating above a platform. I want to create an animation with fluid slowly overflowing from within the apple and leaking drops down the apple, to the platform, and eventually off into an outflow.

I get mixed results every time I try to bake this. The common outcomes are that the domain won't bake, the domain will bake into a blob with no movement, the fluid will flow at an angle, and the fluid will explode everywhere as one giant mass. The variables that most obviously seem to affect the simulation is the volume initiation.

If someone has experience with any form of overflowing fluid simulation, advice would be welcome. Again, I'm really new to this program, so I wouldn't be surprised if I'm just making a ton of stupid mistakes. Thanks!

Comment: I tried your file. You have to add a negative velocity to the inflow's Z direction, change the obstacle's "Volume Initialization" to shell and increase the simulation's resulotion to at least 100. I advise to make an other lowpoly obstacle instead of the apple (duplicate and decimate it, turn of render visiblity and remove the fluid sim from the original). The tabletop's normals are flipped, so fix them in edit mode.

Comment: Trying this soon, I'll let you know how it works

Comment: That all helped a lot, thanks man!